# Where is zxing Android CaptureActivity defined?

Tags: android, zxing

I am following the steps outlined at http://techiedreams.com/android-zxing-barcode-scanner-integration/ to embed QR scanning into my Android app. Instead of building the .jar files myself, I have downloaded them directly from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/.

The problem is none of the jar files below contain com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity class that is required for integration.

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/3.1.0/core-3.1.0.jar
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/android-core/3.1.0/android-core-3.1.0.jar
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/android-integration/3.1.0/android-integration-3.1.0.jar

All these jars are at the latest version as of this post. Wondering if I missed something. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is not a library component and you are not meant to call it that way. The source is available but it is not distributed as a Maven artifact. It is part of an app.

Comment: See guidance on license issues if you're copying source: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/License-Questions Please don't clone the UI; it's not permitted. Reusing source code is.

Comment: @SeanOwen, let me test my understanding - it's OK for me to use the source code for _some_ of the UI components if I composite them sufficiently different than the "Barcode Scanner" application uses them? My rationale for the reuse is that you've solved some sticky issues with connecting the camera and view port that I'd rather not just re-write, however simply embedding your UI (via subclassing CaptureActivity) would not be ok. (Scan by Intent is not palatable to us for a handful of reasons)